# Отношение один ко многим в Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, relation

Есть две таблицы - Админы и Заявки. Я создал между ними отношение один ко многим, но при добавлении Заявки с одним и тем же Админом система выдает ошибку -

```
Не удается вставить повторяющуюся строку ключа в объект "dbo.Заявки" с уникальным индексом "KEY_Заявки_Код_Админа". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (8).
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.
```

А вот сами таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Админы (
  Код INT IDENTITY
 ,Пользователи VARCHAR(50) NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Админы PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Код)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Заявки (
  Код INT IDENTITY
 ,ФИО VARCHAR(50) NULL
 ,Отдел VARCHAR(50) NULL
 ,Проблема VARCHAR(50) NULL
 ,Устройство VARCHAR(50) NULL
 ,ДатаОткрытия DATETIME2 NULL
 ,ДатаЗакрытия DATETIME2 NULL
 ,Код_Админа INT NULL
 ,Наличие VARCHAR(10) NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Заявки PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Код)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Заявки WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Заявки_Админы FOREIGN KEY (Код_Админа) REFERENCES dbo.Админы (Код)
GO
```

Comment: сайт с кратинкой не открывается. вы бы ее текстом скопировали в сам вопрос

Comment: Исправил........

Comment: картинка завтра протухнет, а на SO все должно быть в самом вопросе, что бы он оставался актуальным всегда. Скажу по секрету, что если нажать Ctrl+C на открытом диалоговом окне с ошибкой его текст должен оказаться в буфере обмена. там вроде даже мышкой выделять не обязательно (особенно если не выделяется)

Comment: Благодарствую за лайфхак

Comment: И судя по тексту ошибки у вас помимо приведенной структуры в вопросе есть еще уникальный индекс с названием  KEY_Заявки_Код_Админа тут вы его не привели. И именно он все портит, потому что уникальный. попробуйте его просто удалить (`drop index KEY_Заявки_Код_Админа`) ну и при желании пересоздать его, только не уникальным